# Почему не работает $_COOKIE внутри кастомной функции вордпресса?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookie, woocommerce

При добавлении товара в корзину у меня записывается кука с id поста с которого был добавлен товар.

кука пишется с именем 'idp' а в значении соответственно id. Кука пишется исправно и в момент подтверждения оплаты она уже на месте. проверено.

А вот дальше в момент когда оплата произведена и заказ переходит в стадию "завершён" я пытаюсь взять из куков нужную инфу и ничего не выходит.

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'ustanovka_oplaty');

function ustanovka_oplaty( $post_id ) {
    $idp = $_COOKIE['idp'];
}
```

в чём может быть проблема?

Может есть альтернативный простой способ передать в заказ ид поста на котором был добавлен товар?

Куки устанавливаются так:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpcd_set_cookie', 1 );
  function wpcd_set_cookie() {
  if(isset( $_POST[ 'idp' ] ) ) :
    $cookie_value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'idp' ] );
    setcookie( 'idp', $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 999), "/" ); // 86400 = 1 day

    header("Refresh:0");


endif;
}
```

Comment: возможно вы, неправильно устанавливаете куки. Покажите полный код, где происходит запись кук.

Comment: Куки устанавливаются, много раз проверял. 

add_action( 'init', 'wpcd_set_cookie', 1 );
function wpcd_set_cookie() {
 if(isset( $_POST[ 'idp' ] ) ) :
  $cookie_value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ 'idp' ] );
  setcookie( 'idp', $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 999), "/" ); // 86400 = 1 day

  // Now refresh so the header changes get captured
  header("Refresh:0");

  //exit;
 endif;

Comment: А как вы проверяли, что куки установлены? Код ни о чем не говорит. В браузере вы видите эти куки?

Comment: да, конечно, в браузере появляются